# Font not found (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts

I've tried to install the font Myriad Pro Regular for the app I'm working on.
[image]

However, while the app runs smoothly and shows the custom font. It still gives me an warning.

Things I've tried was cleaning and I've tried enabling this: [image]

Which gave me this warning and didn't solve to problem either: [image]

I've tried to print the name of the font I'm using (which gave me: `Optional("MyriadPro-Regular")`)

From here I'm stuck and I don't know other things I could do to prevent this.
Tips?

Comment: What happened when you [did this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1649/_index.html)?

Comment: Nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

Try this step

1- Go to **build phases**

2- drag drop your font into **Copy Bundle Resources**

[image]

Comment: It still says: "MyriadPro-Regular" font not found.